# How to find and replace entry with a new line

Tags: notepad++

I have entries in a code that look like this

> hit_power=0.57

These entries have different variables like 0.4, 0.65, 0.55 and so on, and there is dozen of them in every file. I want to replace all hit_power= entries with hit_power=0.5, but when i try to find hit_power= and replace it with hit_power=0.5 it will replace it but the former argument of function will stay, so for example i replace hit_power=0.65 to hit_power=0.5, and in th result i will get hit_power=0.50.65. How do i remove an entry with hit_power= function and replace it with new function and an argument?

Answer (score 1):

In the replace window use this text in Find `hit_power=[0-9].[0-9]*` and set the *Search Mode* to **Regular expression**.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

Find what: `(?<=hit_power=)\d\.\d+`
Replace with: `0.5`

`(?<=hit_power=)` is a [positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), that makes sure there is `hit_power=` before the digits, but it's a zero length assertion and doesn't capture it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there's a tabulator[or few spaces] after hit_power= equation. So it can't find the phrase. So is there any way to find a line with

```
 hit_power=
```

erase the line which the phrase occupy with all marks and arguments after it, and then replace with a new line, with new phrase? 
It would be like this:

Find all lines with

```
hit_power
```

Remove line[s] with hit_power and all spaces,tabs, marks, arguments after it, completely, for example:

> `hit_power=      0.57`
>   `hit_power=      0.43`
>   `hit_power=      0.52`

and replace with

> hit_power=0.5
>       hit_power=0.5
>       hit_power=0.5

The formula that was provided by some answers in this topic, were enough to find hit_power=x and replace it with hit_power=0.5. But it can't find phrase when there are spaces/tabs after = mark.

Here;s the actual code:
http://pastebin.com/eLagUcCB

Ok found the answer, just need to use formula

Find

```
hit_power.*
```

Replace with

```
hit_power=0.5
```

Thanks for answers nevertheless!